# How to remove a part with the same word with Bash

Tags: bash, sed

I have a bunch of files in a directory and I'd like to remove a part of words from each file.
Each file has different width and height number and I'd like to remove them.

I use the following now but there are more numbers and I think there must be a better way to do it.

```
sed -i 's/width="12"//' ./*.*
sed -i 's/width="16"//' ./*.*
sed -i 's/width="24"//' ./*.*
sed -i 's/width="25"//' ./*.*
sed -i 's/width="45"//' ./*.*
sed -i 's/height="12"//' ./*.*
sed -i 's/height="16"//' ./*.*
sed -i 's/height="24"//' ./*.*
...
...
```

I appreciate your help.
Thank you.

Comment: Can you give us part of source files and what you expect as result?

Comment: Are you working with files in any particular format, such as XML, JSON etc? If so, there are much more efficient and faster ways of doing what you want to do. You would also be better helped by supplying an example input file, and showing what that file should look like after processing.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the input is XML, maybe something like

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <tag width="23" height="34"/>
  <tag alt="something something" width="23" height="34"/>
  <tag width="23" alt="something else" height="34"/>
  <tag width="abba">Very wide</tag>
</root>
```

... then, you may remove the `width` and `height` attributes from every document node that has them using `xmlstarlet` like so:

```bash
xmlstarlet ed --delete '//@width' --delete '//@height' file.xml
```

... which, given our example document, would generate

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <tag/>
  <tag alt="something something"/>
  <tag alt="something else"/>
  <tag>Very wide</tag>
</root>
```

Doing this on all files with a filename suffix of `.xml` in the current directory (assuming there are not too many of them):

```bash
xmlstarlet ed --inplace --delete '//@width' --delete '//@height' ./*.xml
```

The edits to each file will be made in-place due to the use of the `--inplace` option.

Answer (score 1):

- `\(pattern\)` - grouping
- `foo\|bar` - OR operator
- `[a-z]` - range of characters (be careful with locales)
- `\{m,n\}` - repetition of previous pattern, not using m or n means 0 or infinite, respectively

=> `\(width\|height\)="[0-9]\{1,\}"` is a regular expression that matches `width` or `height` followed by `=` and any positive integer number within double quotes.

A good guide on regular expressions (and more) can be found here: [The Grymoire](https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Regular.html)

**However**, note that the formats you present are typical for e.g. XML and there are some dangers when working on those with REGEX-tools. Usually matching parsers should be preferred.

Comment: Since the OP is using GNU sed for `-i`, they could alternatively write the command a bit more concisely by enabling EREs with `sed -Ei 's/(width|height)="[0-9]+"//'`.